# How to authenticate to Microsoft dynamics with a client secret?

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I'm trying to authenticate a request to Dynamics using the app's client id and the application key. This is failing in a web app project in visual studio (debugging locally). Below is the code I'm trying to use. It looks like I'm getting an auth token back to pass in but it throws this error:

**The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Bearer authorization_uri=https://login.windows.net/....**

---

```
        string organizationUrl = "https://myurl.dynamics.com";
        string clientId = "myclientid";
        string appKey = "myclientsecret";
        string aadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
        string tenantID = "mytenantid";
        ClientCredential clientcred = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadInstance + tenantID);
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(organizationUrl, clientcred);
        var requestedToken = authenticationResult.AccessToken;

        using (var sdkService = new OrganizationWebProxyClient(GetServiceUrl(organizationUrl), false))
        {
            sdkService.HeaderToken = requestedToken;
            OrganizationRequest request = new OrganizationRequest()
            {
                RequestName = "WhoAmI"
            };
            WhoAmIResponse response = sdkService.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest()) as WhoAmIResponse;
            Console.WriteLine(response.UserId);
        }
```

Comment: Are you getting a valid token? I request my auth token from here: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{Tenancy ID}}/oauth2/token`